# Modal em jquery não abre

Tags: php, jquery, modal

Estou montando uma página que ao fazer uma busca no banco de dados, retorna uma tabela com os dados encontrados. Nessa tabela um td trás um link e passa um registro, ao mesmo tempo. Clicando no link devia abrir um modal mas não está dando certo. Quando abro minha página ele abre o modal direto sem que eu clique no link. Me ajudem por favor :(

script dentro do html:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

                            if($.cookie('modal') !== undefined){

                                $('#modal').css('display','none');
                            }

                            $('.pagina').click(function(){
                                    $('#modal').fadeIn(1000);
                            });

                            $('.fechar, #modal').click(function(event){
                                window.location.reload();
                                if(event.target !== this){
                                    return;
                                }
                                $('#modal').fadeOut(500);
                                $.cookie('modal', '1', { expires: 7 });

                            });
                        });
```

CSS:

```
#modal{ background:rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; left:0; top:0; } 
.modal-box{ background:#FFF; width:100%; height:600px; position:static;}
.fechar{ padding:5px 10px; border:1px solid #CCC; position:absolute; right:3px; top:3px; border-radius:7px; color:#CCC; cursor:pointer;}
.fechar:hover{ color:#666; border-color:#666;}
```

Minha div que devia abrir o modal:

```
<div id="modal">
                <div class="modal-box">
                    <div class="modal-box-conteudo"></div>
                    <div class="fechar">X</div> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

E a tabela gerada no php:

```
echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"; echo "<a href=\"#".$dados['nu_sequencial']."\" class=\"pagina\">Ver Grafico</a><br />"; echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo "$dados[uf]<br />"; echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo "$dados[municipio]<br />"; echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo "$dados[dt_ano]<br />"; echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo "$dados[candidato]<br />"; echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>"; echo "$dados[candidatou]<br />"; echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
```

Comment: Olá, quando carrega no link que erro é que dá? Consegue fazer uma simulação no JSFiddle? Ficará mais facil para ajudar

Comment: oie @TiagoGomes obrigada pela boa vontade eu já consegui :)

Comment: Ainda bem :).
Voce pode responder tambem à sua pergunta e marcar como certo, assim poderá ajudar alguem que tenha o mesmo constragimento.